# How to get width and height of image from this function?

Tags: jquery, function

How can I take value of `w` and `h` out side the below code. I need to get the width and height of each image that is selected to upload.

```
     var widt;
            var hit;
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = function (_file) {
                image.src = _file.target.result;              // url.createObjectURL(file);
                image.onload = function () {
                    var w = this.width,
                        h = this.height,
                        t = file.type,                           // ext only: // file.type.split('/')[1],
                        n = file.name
                    widt = w;
                    hit = h;
                };
            };
console.log(widt);
```

Here `console.log` returns `undefined`.

Comment: This either off-topic because it’s caused by a typo (`widt` — `width`) or a dpulicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321).

Comment: Just a small typo mistake ..please correct the `width` spelling

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: corrected the typo but still the same result

Comment: you are logging your variable before it is set...

Answer (score 0):

Your variable name is `widt` and your are using `width` in the console log. Try:

```
console.log(widt);
```

Also, put that console log inside the `image.onload` function to get the correct response.

Comment: If it’s caused by a simple typo, vote to close instead of answering.

Comment: variable name changed to 'widt' . Also I need both the values outside the function .Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the semi-colon at the end of following line of code

```
  n = file.name
```

Answer (score 0):

1. "console.log(widh);" change to "console.log(widt);"
2. put "console.log(widt);" into "image.onload" function.

code:

```
image.onload = function () {
  var w = this.width,
      h = this.height,
      t = file.type,                           
      n = file.name;
  widt = w;
  hit = h;
  console.log(widt);
};
```